# EF Linq include nested arrays

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-code-first

I have 3 classes in EF-Code-First

```
public class User {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Flat> Flats { get; set; }
}

public class Flat {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual House House { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}

public class House {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Flat> Flats { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to get all users.

I do:

```
var Result = _storage.Users
    .Include(x => x.Flats)
    .Include(y => y.Flats.Select(z => z.House))
    .ToList();
```

And in **Result** I have **Users** with **Flats**, but **Flats** don't have their **Houses**.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You currently have House in Flat, Flat in House, Flat in User and User in Flat. This is really confusing. This may lead to cyclic dependency. Not sure what u want to achieve here

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add one include, the one to the deepest level:

```
var Result = _storage.Users
.Include(user => user.Flats.Select(flat => flat.Houses))
.ToList();
```

This will automatically include all Houses properties as well as all Flat properties and the Houses properties

Other Flat Collections will not be included. For those you would need an extra Include.